# Attempt to use @BindView for an already bound ID 0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

Android Studio Build fails with:

```
Attempt to use @BindView for an already bound ID 0 on 'mConnectionMessage'


Fragment.java:53: error: Attempt to use @BindView for an already bound ID 0 on 'mConnectionMessage'. 
    ImageView mConnectionImage;
              ^
```

Here's the part of the code that causes the problem:

```
    @BindView(R2.id.display_discovery_state_icon)
    ImageView mConnectionImage;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **Short Answer:**

Under:

```
build.gradle
```

change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

## **Long Answer:**

Android Studio update is the root cause of the issue.

Here's the update:

```
"To take advantage of the latest features, improvements, and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin from the current version 3.5.3 to version 3.6.0 and Gradle to version 5.6.4. Release notes"
```

which changes:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
```

and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

The problem can be reproducible merely by making the above changes manually (not necessarily running the update).

**Note:**
I could reproduce the problem and fix, both on windows and mac.

Comment: navid vafaei - do you mean that gradle update has a bug?

Comment: @MustafaHussain I want to be more conservative and word it like: "Gradle update causes a bug" :)

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade the version of butterknife to 10.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Are you using butternife?
In my case, I upgraded to version 10.2.1 (com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.1) and no longer received the message.

I'm using gradle 3.6.1.

Comment: Great! Thanks bro, this gonna make me add view binding side by side to ButterKnife to replace it.